# PHP 5.4.7 breaks Wordpress 3.4.2

Tags: php, wordpress

My web hosting company has upgraded PHP to version 5.4.7.

I have no choice over the matter.

What happens now is that every single page just loads a blank white page. I created a basic page with echo 'hello world'; and it works fine.

Please can anybody advise on how to fix this?

I am using Wordpress 3.4.2

Comment: have you checked the wordpress support forums? Is anyone else suggesting the same problem>

Comment: Please add some error messages from wordpress. Are your rewrite-settings (.htaccess) still OK?

Comment: It might be something to talk to your web host about, but I would suggest that you test it locally by installing the same php version and enabling [debug mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), and seeing if there are any errors or if something shows up in the logs.

Comment: Remember to post the solution here when you find it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP 5.4.7 isn't breaking WordPress itself; it must be breaking a plugin that can't run 5.4.7

Try:

1) Renaming your plugins folder to old-plugins to force deactivation of all plugins and see if that helps.

2) It could be a problem with the theme; change to the default twentyeleven theme

Comment: Thanks, podpress was the cause, but I am not sure if the hosting company did anything or not. I deleted podpress and re-installed and all is well.

Answer (score 0):

I have read somewhere that you need to update your mysql password (and wp-config.php), I think later versions of php can't handle the older mysql passwords.